# UICollectionView: why with background view my cells seem transparent?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I've added an image to the view under collectionview with the code:

```
    let backGroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Background.png"))
    self.view.addSubview(backGroundView)
```

When I build and run seems that background image is over the cells and "oscurate" them. Why?? I would like an effect where the cells are over the background images

Note: if I add the background image directly to the collectionview the problem is the same

I can't attach the example image because I don't have 10 reputations, but i can send you via mail.

Thanks
Mauro

Comment: addSubview adds the subview on top of all existing subviews. Perhaps you want insertSubview:atIndex:? Index 0 will be the bottom of the stack.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved.

I added `self.view.bringSubviewToFront(theCollectionView)` and now the background image is placed on the background.